# public partial class Form

Tags: c#, winforms

If I create a partial class of Form1 is there a way to access the controls that are on the form designer thru intellisense?

```
namespace PracticeUI1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Button1.Text = "blah";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and then tell _us_?

Comment: I'm not seeing the controls in intellisense but I wasn't sure if I was missing something in case someone out there has done it already. However, I can create an event handler in the new partial class and it will compile and work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend where you will initialize your button, lets say you are declaring in the same class and you do it as

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
```

inside Class Form, than you will be able to reach only from this part of class Form or from another partial class form in another file, but you woudnt be able to access it from the same namespace. I think you got the logic.

By the way for the answer with

```
this.button1
```

it's actually doesn't matter if you will include `this.` or you will not

Answer (score 4):

If you have already defined

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
```

the next partial class is (maybe even without `public` modifier)

```
public partial class Form1
```

Also be sure that you are at the same namespace

Answer (score 4):

Type `this.` and IntelliSense now has enough context to know that you are interested in a member of your form class.  And pops down the completion window:

[image]

A form class has a lot of members, you can help narrow down the choices by typing more.  Press the Up/Down keys to select, Tab key to use the suggestion.

Note that the default name of a button starts with a lower-case b, not with a B.  Exactly the kind of mistake that IntelliSense helps you avoid.